# my python code should print the number positions of each word in a sentence but it doesn't work

Tags: python

my python code currently looks like this:

```
list = []
lists = "" 
sentence = str(input("Enter a sentence to be translated into numbers: ")).lower()
numbers = sentence.split(' ')
list.append(lists)
print(lists)
for i,j in enumerate(sentence.split(' ')):
    print (i,j)
```

i want it to print a number according to the position of a word in a sentence

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What does it actually do and how does that differ from what you want it to do?

Comment: it should print the position of each word in a sentence (hello world hello world would be 1,2,1,2 but the code just does 1,2,3,4)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to assign a number to each word in the given sentence, and then replace all words with their numbers.

You can use this:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence to be translated into numbers: ").lower().split(" ")
numbers = list(set(sentence))
result = []
for word in sentence:
    result.append(numbers.index(word))
```

What we are doing here is the following:

1. Get the sentence from the user and split it into a list using <kbd>space</kbd> as a delimiter.
2. Make a set out of the sentence list. This removes all duplicates, leaving only one instance of each word. Then, convert that set into a list.
3. Initialize a variable `result` which will hold, well, the result.
4. Loop through all words in the sentence.

   - For each word in the sentence, append it's index in `numbers` to `result`.

DEMO:

```
Enter a sentence to be translated into numbers: Hello world hello world
>>> [1, 0, 1, 0]

Enter a sentence to be translated into numbers: This is a test sentence with only a single duplicate
>>> [4, 2, 0, 6, 8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 5]
```